# Recieving following error

Tags: go

I am recieving an error while compilation.

Root cause is the file has import of `context` package, but however during compilation `github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context` is getting referred a, any pointers on as how to make it to refer to `context` import instead of docker's `vendor` package

Summarizing the issue, 
import in the file is as follows

```
import "golang.org/x/net/context"
```

there is a method call which takes context object as an argument, however, there are two repositories which have context ,

- golang.org/x/net/context
- github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context

During compilation based on length go is selecting the 2 repository. But method needs the 1st one  golang.org/x/net/context. hence the type error in code snippet is recieved

```
    "-X main.version=dev-49-gc8cc01b -X main.commit=c8cc01b -X     main.branch=master" ./...
 github.com/influxdata/telegraf/plugins/inputs/docker
 plugins/inputs/docker/docker.go:103: cannot use c (type *client.Client) as     type DockerClient in assignment:
    *client.Client does not implement DockerClient (wrong type for  ContainerList method)
            have ContainerList("github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context".Context, types.ContainerListOptions) ([]types.Container, error)
            want ContainerList("context".Context, types.ContainerListOptions) ([]types.Container, error) make: *** [build] Error 2  sh-4.2# vi plugins/inputs/docker/docker.go
```

Comment: Refrase your problem. Hard to understand.

Comment: Check your imports. I've had cases where the IDE (IntelliJ or similar) had decided it knows better what to import "on the fly" and so I ended up with having imported absolutely wrong packages...

Comment: Here aliases would be handy :-)

Comment: You should not import libraries with vendor directories. You need to move the vendored packages into your project. Any of the vendoring tools can do this for you.

Comment: @Volker: this particular case is where aliases actually shouldn't be used (i.e. docker should not create an alias for its vendored copy of x/net/context). The type mismatch is because of a library dependency which has a vendor directory. "Library" packages with a vendor directory have to be address specifically if you share any transitive dependencies. Hopefully there will be a consensus on dependency management tools soon, and this can be better documented. Though if you need to use the stdlib `context` and `x/net/context`, that is going to be painful without type aliases :/

Comment: Agree with Jim, I have tried aliasing also , but it gives an error saying that using vendor library is not allowed. "golang.org/x/net/context", . One thing which i tried was renaming the  context directory of docker and it worked. But wonder if this is the right approach

Comment: @rohitsingh: no the right approach is to properly vendor the package. Because you're using the docker package as a dependency, and it is vendoring dependencies itself, it requires you to use the same technique.

Answer (score -1):

Two options I can think of:

1. Add an alias for the context import, e.g.

   goContext golang.org/x/net/context
   docContext github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context
2. Break the context dependencies into two files, or packages